# Sqlalalchemy postgresql insert statement ignore duplicates

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to bulk insert data to postgres using `SQLAlchemy`, but can't find out how to say it to ignore duplicates values by unique constraint

My code

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert

stmt = insert(User, inline=True)

values = [{"id": 1, "name": "David"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Cris"}]

session.execute(stmt, values)
session.commit()
```

Got such error

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint  "uq_users_name"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default sqlalchemy doesn't support `ignore_duplicates` option, so we need to add custom method to sqlalchemy query compiler by simply adding `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` string to the end of the query

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles

@compiles(Insert, 'postgresql')
def ignore_duplicates(insert, compiler, **kw):
    s = compiler.visit_insert(insert, **kw)
    ignore = insert.kwargs.get('postgresql_ignore_duplicates', False)
    return s if not ignore else s + ' ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING'

Insert.argument_for('postgresql', 'ignore_duplicates', None)


stmt = insert(User, postgresql_ignore_duplicates=True, inline=True)

values = [{"id": 1, "name": "David"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Cris"}]

session.execute(stmt, values)
session.commit()
```